# Extra editor on top of default in Custom Post Type

Tags: php, functions, editor

[image]

**Normally** there is one editor by default in any custom post type.

I want one extra + If extra is possible how will we print it in the front end. For a default we do it like this:

```
the_content();
```

what I am visualizing is that really possible?

Answer (score 0):

There are plugins available, such as Advanced Custom Fields, that allow you to add additional content areas. You set up the fields, and choose what post types they will appear on, and then you'll be able to enter information in a WYSIWYG editor basically like the Classic Editor.

ACF saves the data to postmeta rather than post_content, so you then need to adjust your theme templates to specifically call for that postmeta wherever it is needed.

Comment: Thanks @WebElaine w/o plugin would it be a lengthy task?

Comment: Would it be possible to elaborate this: specifically call for that postmeta wherever it is needed.

Comment: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/

Comment: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-posts/